# show toggle read more/less button only if string length is longer than 50 characters

Tags: jquery, html, angular, css

I want to display a "read more/less" button in a table only if the content is longer than 50 characters. The Content in the table is mixed, so there are a few short announcements of about 10 signs, and then some with over 100

```
<div class="col">
<span ng-class="{'show_all_text' : toggle_txt}" >{{text}}</span>
<button ng-click="{'show_all_text' : toggle_txt}" ng-if=" text.length > 50" class="show_more_txt btn">Show / Hide more</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Mate, you are expected to post your current code within your question if you want any answers.

Answer (score -1):

On your read more/less button add `ngIf`.

```
<button *ngIf="content?.length > 50">Read more</button>
```